# NPM package keeps failing to import

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I created a basic NPM package for the first time and I wanted to use it on one of my project which is a Typescript project in `node.js v16.15.0`. Both projects were built on same node.js version.
I get this error when I tried to import the package into the project that I am working on:

`Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module globaltype.js not supported

Instead change the require of globaltype.js in ... to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

`

Here is the typescript config file for the package:

```
 {"files": ["src/globaltype.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "es2015",
      "declaration": true,

     "outDir": "./build",
      
      "esModuleInterop": true, 
       "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,  
       "strict": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
  }}
```

The package.json file

```
{
  "name": "nodecustomerrorhandler",
  "version": "1.0.13",
  "description": "basic error handling module for node basic projects",
  "main": "build/globaltype.js",
  "types": "build/globaltype.d.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  }
}
```

The package code:

```
export class GlobalErrorClass {
   //codes ran here
 }
```

The project where I want to use the package:

```
{"files": ["src/globaltype.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
     "rootDir": "./",                                  
    "moduleResolution": "node",
     "typeRoots": ["/src/globals.d.ts"], 

      "outDir": "src/build",
      
       "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,   
       "strict": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
  }}
```

The project package.json

```
{
  "name": "affiliatesystem",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "test.file.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn src/server.ts"
  },
 
  },
}
```

Now, if I export the package with typescript setting to be `"module": "CommonJS",` and import it this way:
`const GlobalErrorClass =  require('nodecustomerrorhandler')`, it works well, no error and no issue.

I guess this has to do with my typescript setting and the environment I want to use the package. How do I handle this?
I also added `"type": "module"` to the project package.json file, I kept having error.

I shared my code above

Comment: So you cannot use require _unless_ you use commonjs. Sounds like you tried commonjs and it removed the error. Why not do that?

Comment: I was thinking that modern applications are moving away from using require syntax to use import syntax